# Excel VBA - Data from worksheet in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I am trying to pull data from a worksheet in another workbook and it isn't working properly.  I'm not getting an error in the code but it is not pulling the data from the worksheet I want but rather whatever worksheet is open when the workbook opens.  I read somewhere that there is no need to activate the worksheet so I am not sure what is wrong with the following code:

```
Dim prfile1 As String
Dim prfile2 As String
Dim filepath As String
Dim checktotal As Integer
Dim checkrng As Range
Dim emunber As String

prfile1 = Worksheets("setup").Range("B10").Value
prfile2 = Worksheets("setup").Range("B7").Value
filepath = Worksheets("setup").Range("e10").Value
emunber = Worksheets("ReprintOld").Range("V3").Value

Workbooks.Open filepath & prfile2
Windows(prfile2).Activate
Sheets(emunber).Activate
checktotal = Workbooks(prfile2).Worksheets(emunber).Range("AE1")

With Workbooks(prfile2).Worksheets(emunber)

    Set checkrng = Range(Range("U5"), Range("U" & 4 + checktotal).End(xlDown))

End With

Windows(prfile1).Activate
MsgBox emunber
MsgBox checktotal
MsgBox checkrng.Address
```

Comment: Have you stepped through to see what's going on?

Comment: `Set checkrng = Range(Range(...`  What workbook/worksheet do you expect that Range to be? I assume you want to link it to the `With` statement, yeah?  You need to qualify those ranges with a preceding `.`, e.g. `Set checkrng = .Range(.Range("US"), .Range("U" ...)`

Comment: *I read somewhere that there is no need to activate the worksheet* This is true, but you need to reference the worksheet where you have the data you want. You can do it with objects and variables, or you can do it activating that sheet first and then, rest of your code.

Comment: And yes, as @BruceWayne said, you need the dot in `With...End With` statement. I upvoted his/her comment because your code looks code. Try what he/she said.

Comment: ok, adding the `.` before `Range` gets it to pull the data from the correct sheet, but the range is not correct.  In column `U` I have a dynamic list of check numbers starting at row 5 and in cell `AE1` is a count of the check numbers so my range should be from row 5 to the last check number (4 plus checktotal) but it is giving me a range from `U5` to the last cell with data in the column

Comment: oh, I'm an idiot.  originally I wrote the code for the last cell with data then changed it and forgot to delete the `.End(xlDown)` duh!